What are the next steps to debug why nothing I'm trying to print is displaying in my terminal?
I'm using Visual Studio Code to work through a C++ course and am trying to finish a section challenge. Problem is, none of my cout are displaying anything.
In both of my functions as well as my main method, I have cout set up to print something. None of them are displaying anything in the terminal. Logically, I should be getting something unless there's something I'm just unaware of.
I'm not sure if this helps, but when I run my program, this is all that displays in my terminal
PS C:\Users\Me\Workspaces\Udemy-CPP-Course-1>  & 'c:\Users\Me\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.20.5-win32-x64\debugAdapters\bin\WindowsDebugLauncher.exe' '--stdin=Microsoft-MIEngine-In-5y04hemj.h0d' '--stdout=Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-eu5yk1st.ktm' '--stderr=Microsoft-MIEngine-Error-y4av4ltd.u2b' '--pid=Microsoft-MIEngine-Pid-od1vghvl.444' '--dbgExe=C:\mingw64\bin\gdb.exe' '--interpreter=mi'
I've tried running other files from the past that have displayed something, but they all seem to have this issue now, so at the very least, I know it's not something in the code from this one section challenge.
EDIT:
Someone recommended checking out this post, but the directory someone in the debugging recommended you delete files from doesn't seem to exist for me. Specifically, this directory: %USERPROFILE%.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.6.0-insiders
Here's what I've found that's different. I've been pushing all of my changes to a repo on GitHub, and I noticed it's been trying to tell me to push changes to files I've never seen before. Here's a list of the files there have apparently been changes in.

ProjectSettings.json
slnx.sqlite
VSWorkspaceState.json
Browse.VC.db
DocumentLayout.json
.wsuo
three seperate files with a mix of numbers, letters, and dashes
ending in ".vsidx"

At the recommendation of another user, I also tried running the code from a seperate Command Line window and the code ran just fine, displaying exactly what I expected.
If push comes to shove, I'm willing to delete and reinstall VS Code, but I'd rather avoid that so I don't need to reinstall all the extensions I have in place nor get the settings the way I like them.
Does anyone have any recommendations on what to do next?

what happens if you run it in debug mode under a debugger ?

Can't replicate https://godbolt.org/z/W5sxTMjsY You likely watch a wrong terminal window.

@AhmedAEK That was what I got when I hit "Run and Debug". I was using C++(GDB/LLDB).

@273K what AhmedAEK said. That was the only terminal open. I made sure to close out all of them to make sure.

@cavlier145 My next step would be to take VSCode out of the equation. Try compiling and running your program from the command line. If it works then you know that VSCode is the problem, if not then you need to fix things from the command line, before you try it again in VSCode.

@john 273K was able to show me that in a different compiler, my code ran as I expected it to. Is that at least somewhat the same as running from the command line? I can always try running it from the command line anyways, but I figured I'd ask regardless.

One good next step would be to focus on the specific problem. The problem is "none of my cout are displaying anything" so get rid of everything else: #include <iostream> int main() { std::cout << "Where is the output?\n": } Simple and short. Does this give you output? (If not, make this the [mre] of your question.)

@cavlier145 273K shows that the code is OK. but there still could be issues on your system that have nothing to do with VSCode. So I think a command line build and run is a good idea.

@john Forgive me if this is a stupid question, but how do I run it from the command line? I've tried googling it, but have been having issues with getting it to cooperate. The file name is "Section Challenge.exe". And I have made sure to cd to the correct directory.

@cavlier145 Well first I would seriously advise against putting spaces in a file name, it's just another thing that can go wrong, and it could even be the cause of the original problem. Something like "./Section Challenge.exe" should work (those quotes are necessary because of the space in the file name).

@john Running it from the command line works beautifully. As for the space, thank you for the advice. Though, I have 5 other files I've created for other chapters with the same name and this is the first time I have ever experienced this problem. What would be next? Please don't say uninstalling and reinstalling VS Code.

how about uninstalling VSCode and installing Visual Studio Community edition, everyday we get more than 10 people complaining about problems in VSCode but no one ever complains about Visual Studio Community edition.

@cavlier145 Well now the issue is VSCode which is not something I know so well, it's also difficult because VSCode has so many options. Anything you can think of to narrow down the problem will help.

@cavlier145 And I do agree with Ahmed AEK. VSCode is extremely complex and not anything special, but for some reason it's absurdly popular. If you don't have to use it then I suggest you don't.

@AhmedAEK I actually use VS Community for C# projects. You're right that there are many things about it that are preferable (especially the predictive AI). The more childish part of me is just lamenting how convenient the customization of VS Code is on top of the different extensions. If there was a good middle ground between them, I'd prefer that. I will give it a try though because you're right, there is plenty of merit to it.

@jhole I checked it out and the files I'm seeing someone suggest you try deleting don't exist. Specifically, this directory couldn't be found  %USERPROFILE%.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.6.0-insiders. Not sure if this solution is relevant anymore or if they have since patched it out since this is about 3 years old.

Apparently, you have used VS Code with some success before (you say you elaborately configured many of the extensions which seems to indicate you were using it). Is that correct?

You can delete your source code from the question, it is a distraction (or replace it with a "Hello World!"). Your problem is in the setup.
You have two main ways to go about this: Use a fresh (possibly parallel) VS Code installation and re-create your preferred configuration, noting which step makes it stop working (if at all); or revert your existing installation to the original state in which it last worked, step-by step, until it works again, hopefully.
You made it clear that you'd prefer not to re-install. That leaves you with option two. When you start changing the existing installation, focus on things that seem likely to redirect the output. For example, it seems likely that the redirection '--stdout=Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-eu5yk1st.ktm' tries to connect to a debugger and that something goes wrong there. I don't know VS Code at all, so my advice can only be general, but:

Try to switch to a "Release" configuration. That will likely not try to start a debugger.
Try to switch to another toolchain, e.g. from MinGW to msvc or vice versa.


Thanks. I will give this a try at some point when I have enough brain power to figure out more stuff (because beyond putting code in and running it, I don't know much about VS Code either. It's just good for running individual files rather than the whole project.) Once I do it, I'll make sure to update.
